# php + fgetcsv does not support some special characters

Tags: php, csv, encoding, special-characters, fgetcsv

I am uploading csv file and its content is fetching using the function fgetcsv,

I am already using utf8 encoding still some characters are gets converted in to ?

Following are some of those charcters:

```
ť  č ň
```

Is there any way which accept all the special charcters of any language which supports while reading CSV file.

How to add the BOM element while reading CSV

Comment: fgetcsv() doesn't particularly care; what charset is the csv file? How are you displaying the data?

Comment: how are you sure that all stuff (file input, server, the way you check your output) is really UTF-8? to me it still looks like an encoding issue

Comment: I am storing this data in database. but currently I am just reading it from CSV and this characters get converted to ? before any processing

Answer (score 0):

Try `fgets` instead of `fgetcsv`. fgetcsv() tries to be binary-safe, but it's actually not.

Comment: fgets also gives same result. Some of the characters are correct but some display like ?